# Determine whether $L$ defined by $Lu = u' + |u|$ is a linear operator.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing, operator-theory

Determine whether $L$ defined by $Lu = u' + |u|$ is a linear operator.

I claim yes, but only in certain cases.

*Proof*

Suppose $L$ is a linear operator then by definition

$$L(av + bw) = (av + bw)' + \left|av + bw\right| = a\left(v' + \left|v\right|\right) + b\left(w' + \left|w\right|\right) = aLv + bLw$$

which implies

$$\left|av + bw\right| = a\left|v\right| + b\left|w\right| \tag{$\star$}$$

Applying the triangle inequality to the left side of $\,(\star)$

$$ \left|av + bw\right| \leq \left|a\right|\left|v\right| + \left|b\right|\left|w\right|$$

So this contradicts the supposition that $L$ is linear in general.

---

Looking back I believe I should reconstruct the proof in two parts: (i) proving $L$ is linear with the restrictions that $\,a,b\geq0\, $and that $v(x), w(x)$ are the same sign with respect to each other and that that sign never changes (but can be zero). (ii) for the second part I will redo the above proof supposing $L$ is linear for all other cases not subject to the restrictions of part (i) and arrive at a contradiction.

Please comment on my approach and validity, because to me it seems like overkill. Is there a non case by case method?

Comment: Linear means no restrictions.

Comment: It makes no sense to say only in special cases.

Comment: @copper.hat Why is that so? We consider cases for determining how other mathematical statements are valid. Like for example, when determining whether a function is differentiable we will often state what set it is differentiable on, rather than simply saying "no" if there exists a point where it is not differentiable.

Comment: The function must be defined on a (linear) subspace, that is how it is defined.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your proof as written is not correct: you haven't reached any contradiction.  Apparently you seem to think the inequality you found is somehow a contradiction but it is not in any obvious way.

Second of all, for $L$ to be linear means that $L(av+bw)=aL(v)+bL(w)$ in *all* cases.  If this equation is true in some cases but not others, then $L$ is simply not linear, rather than "linear in some cases".  Moreover, that means that to answer the question, you just need to find *one* case where it fails: that is all it takes to conclude that $L$ is not linear.

So your goal is just to give *one* counterexample.  That is, you just need to describe *one* way to choose $a,b,v,$ and $w$ such that $L(av+bw)\neq aL(v)+bL(w)$.  The easiest and best way to do this is be completely explicit: actually say what specific numbers $a$ and $b$ are and what functions $v$ and $w$ are, so that you can compute $L(av+bw)$ and $aL(v)+bL(w)$ and see they are not the same.  Using the work you've done so far, it would be enough to just check that $|av+bw|\neq a|v|+b|w|$ in your example.

The casework you propose doing is not helpful.  It is not relevant whether $L(av+bw)=aL(v)+bL(w)$ in some cases (as in your case (i)); the *only* thing you care about proving in this problem is that there exists a case where it isn't true.  (Of course, the fact that $L(av+bw)=aL(v)+bL(w)$ in some cases may be useful in other contexts, if you are interested in more than just this single problem.)

Comment: Why would I not treat cases? Is just common practice that linearity is taken as an "absolute" statement? Because it's common in other areas of math to answer a question like, for $f(x) := |x|$, determine if $f$ is differentiable, with a statement about *where* the function differentiable.  The simple "$f$ is not differentiable" is a poor answer in my opinion.